# Access Path Of File In C++

Tags: c++

I want to access the path of the executable file. I know in python, you can do the following:

```
import os

filePath, fileName = os.path.split(__file__)
```

The code above will get the path of the file, and the name of the file that the lines are in. Is this applicable in C++ (returning the name is more optional)? I do NOT want the source code, only the path of the executable.

PS: if you think this is very little detail, copy paste the code above, paste the following:

```
print(filePath)
```

and run the code in a python intepreter.

PPS: Tried installing POCO or qt, as one of the comments in the first question mentioned, and didn't find out how to install.

PPPS: For more details of why I want the path and what I'm doing it with: I need the path so I can load assets to a game. Sometimes, the program just won't load the image after putting in the name of the file, like other people in tutorials do (albeit the image file is in the same directory). And then I figured out that for python, the code above works, so I'm asking if this is applicable in C++.

Comment: It depends.  There was nothing in standard C++ to deal with file paths until the `filesystem` module in C++17.  If you need to use something older, then it's going to be operating-system specific.  Both Linux and Windows have system APIs to do this.  Which are you using?

Comment: C++ is a compiled language, file that has been used to compile the executable may not be present in the runtime. If you want original source file name then you can use `__FILE__` macro, if you want executable file path then you can use system-specific API, such as `GetModuleFileNameW`

Comment: @TimRoberts I am using Linux.

Comment: @user7860670 Quick check: so if I do something in the main file (say, find the path, then print the path to the console), then compile it, then move the  executable to somewhere else, or delete the source file, will it print the source file's path, or the executable's?

Comment: what are you trying to do? What do you want to do with the path?

Comment: You MUST REMEMBER that compile and execute are two different steps that can happen on different computers.  You can embed the current source file as a constant string using `__FILE__`, but the source file paths are completely meaningless once the file is compiled.  At run-time, you can get the "current directory" and you can find the path to the executable, but that's it.

Comment: First will it expand to source file name, while the other makes it possible to retrieve executable file path.

Comment: In C++ the executable (and depending on how you ran it possibly even the path) will usually be in the `main` function's `argv` parameter's first slot `argv[0]`. `argv[0]` can be left blank if the implementation choses, and embedded systems often do. A full-featured OS often will provide an API function or other method you can count on to track down the executable and path. As stated by others, there is no consistent way to draw a connection from the compiled executable to the source code.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetBasePath wraps [a bunch of platform-specific tricks](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/tree/main/src/filesystem).  The [Linux backend tends to lean on the `/proc/self` filesystem](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/src/filesystem/unix/SDL_sysfilesystem.c#L219).

Comment: @genpfault Thanks! SDL_GetBasePath worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you're getting the path to the file containing the source code that's executing.

In C++, the file containing the source code to what's executing may not exist, or (more often) may exist but be inaccessible (e.g., stored on a system to which you don't have access).

Instead, in C++ the source code is normally compiled to an executable file, and that's what runs. But that executable contains machine-level instructions rather than the C++ source code of the program as the programmer wrote it.

If you want access to the source code at run time, you're almost certainly going to have to do that on your own--make sure a copy of the source code is on the target computer in some location you can find.

The C++ standard library contains basic support for things like searching for a particular file in a file system tree, but it's going to be up to you to put those building blocks together into a system that gives you access to the source code at run-time. Chances are pretty good that in the process, you'll end up needing a few things that are available on most operating systems, but still require code specific to the operating system you're using (e.g., getting the path to the executable file so you can build some path relative to that where you store the source file).

Comment: I'm not exactly trying to access the source code via the executable, but thanks for at least trying to answer! I'll edit my answer to be more specific.

Comment: If you want the name of the executable, then it is held in `argv[0]` with the path component used to invoke the program (could be relative or absolute).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: IMO, trying to use `argv[0]` is almost a lost cause. It might have a full path, or it might have a relative path, or it might be completely empty, or (rarely) contain something else entirely (e.g,. on Windows using `CreateProcess`, you can pass an arbitrary string to show up as the child's `argv[0]`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin - sure, it's no panacea, and I apologize, I should have addressed the comment to the questioner. I was trying to elicit further clarification from their last comment above.  From an earlier comment at the time, the OP indicated he was using Linux, so unless it's on some embedded system, `argv[0]` should at least be populated. Now what's tagged on to the front as a path is a bit dubious and would need exploring with the likes of `readlink()` or POSIX `realpath()`, etc..